# SMS sending through free gateway

Tags: php, sms

Please guide me with sample code for sending sms through website. How to include sms gateway. Please tell me, can i use way2sms.com as gateway?

is it the right way to use? please suggest me only this much of code works?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush(true);


include_once "class.curl.php";
include_once "class.sms.php";

$smsapp=new sms();
$smsapp->setGateway('way2sms'); 


echo "Logging in  ... ";
$smsapp->login('10 digit number','way2sms password');

echo "Sending SMS ... ";
$result=$smsapp->send('receipient number','text message');

if($result=='true')
{
    echo "Message sent";
}
else
{   
    echo "Error encountered : ".$smsapp->getLastError();
}

?>
```

here is my class.curl.php

```
<?php
class sms
{
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $curl;
    var $server;
    var $loginDone;
    var $debugMode;
    var $data;
    var $error;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->curl=new cURL();
    //  $this->curl->setProxy("");
        $this->loginDone=false;
        $this->debugMode=false;
        $this->data=array();
    }
    public function setGateway($serverName)
    {
        switch($serverName)
        {
            case '160by2':
            $this->server='160by2';
            break;

            case 'way2sms':
            $this->server='way2sms';
            break;

            case 'airtel':
            $this->server='airtel';
            break;

            default :
            $this->server='way2sms';

        }
    }
    public function login($username,$password)
    {
        $server=$this->server;

        call_user_func(array($this,"login_$server"),$username,$password);
        $this->loginDone=true;

    }
    public function send($number,$msg)
    {
        $server=$this->server;
        if($this->loginDone)
        return call_user_func(array($this,"send_$server"),$number,$msg);
        else
        {
            echo "<h2>Please login first before sending SMS</h2>";
        }

    }
    private function login_way2sms($username,$password)
    {
        $out=($this->curl->post("http://www.way2sms.com","1=1"));
        $pattern="/Location:(.+?)\n/";
        preg_match($pattern,$out,$matches);
        $domain=trim($matches[1]);

        $this->data['domain']=$domain;

        $out= $this->curl->post("{$domain}auth.cl","username=$username&password=$password&Submit=Sign+in");

        $pattern="/Location:(.+?)\n/";
        preg_match($pattern,$out,$matches);
        $referer=trim($matches[1]);
        $this->data['referer']=$referer;


    }


    private function send_way2sms($number,$msg)
    {
        $domain=$this->data['domain'];
        $html=$this->curl->post("{$domain}jsp/InstantSMS.jsp?val=0","1=1",$this->data['referer']);
        if($this->debugMode)
        {
        echo "<h2>After logging in, the HTML returned by server is</h2>";
        echo $html;
        }

        $pattern = '/name="Action".+?value="(.*)"/';
        preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);

        $custfrom=$matches[1];
        $msg=urlencode($msg);
        $html=$this->curl->post("{$domain}FirstServletsms?custid=","custid=undefined&HiddenAction=instantsms&Action={$custfrom}&login=&pass=&MobNo=$number&textArea=$msg");
        $pattern = '/class="style1">(.+?)<\/span>/';
        preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
        $out=($matches[1]);

        if(!preg_match("/successfully/",$out))
        {
        $this->setError($out);
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
        return true;
        $this->setError("No errors");
        }

    }
    public function getLastError()
    {
        return $this->error;

    }
    private function setError($error)
    {
        $this->error=$error;
    }
    private function login_160by2($username,$password)
    {
    //  $out2=$this->curl->get("http://m.160by2.com");
        $out=$this->curl->post("http://m.160by2.com/LoginCheck.asp?l=1&txt_msg=&mno=","txtUserName=$username&txtPasswd=$password&RememberMe=Yes&cmdSubmit=Login");
        $pattern="/MyMenu.asp\?Msg=(.+?)&/";

        preg_match($pattern,$out,$matches);
        $id=trim($matches[1]);
        $this->data['id']=$id;

    }

    private function send_160by2($number,$msg)
    {
        $msg=urlencode($msg);
        $id=$this->data['id'];
        $out1=$this->curl->post("http://m.160by2.com/SaveCompose.asp?l=1","txt_mobileno=$number&txt_msg=$msg&cmdSend=Send+SMS&TID=&T_MsgId=&Msg=$id");
        //echo $out1;
        $pattern = '/\<table.+?\>(.+)\<\/table/s';
        preg_match($pattern, $out1, $matches);

        $out=strip_tags(@$matches[1]);
        if(count($matches)<1)
        {
        $pattern="/\<div.+?background:.+?yellow.+?\>(.+?)\<\/div\>/s";

        preg_match($pattern,$out1,$matches);

        $out=strip_tags($matches[1]);
        }

//
    //  echo "out is $out";

        if(!preg_match("/successfully/i",$out))
        {

        $this->setError($out);

        return false;
        }
        else
        {
        return true;
        $this->setError("No errors");
        }

    }

    private function login_airtel($username,$password)
    {
        $this->data['username']=$username;
        $this->data['password']=$password;

    }


    private function send_airtel($number,$msg)
    {

    }
}

?>
```

in the place of username and password, which username and password i should use?

Comment: You probably need to ask them, not us

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, or you could use the gateways as provided by the wireless carriers themselves, as then it's as simple as sending them an email with [PHP's mail function](http://php.net/mail).

Where *(Number)* is, you must include their 10 digit phone number. So that means that you must include their area code.

**AT&T**
*(Number)*@txt.att.net

**T-Mobile**
*(Number)*@tmomail.net

**Sprint**
*(Number)*@messaging.sprintpcs.com

**Verizon**
*(Number)*@vtext.com OR *(Number)*@vzwpix.com

Comment: please suggest me, do i need to contact way2sms.com support for making sms gateway or getting the details? sorry. i do not know anything about this. so i am asking from the scratch.

Comment: You do not. All you must do is use the PHP mail function along with their number and their carrier address to email each number the text message you want to send them.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer was accepted.  The asker was trying to send SMS to the Airtel network in India.  This answer only applies to the USA.  Almost nowhere else has recipient-pays SMS and therefore nowhere else has email-to-sms gateways.

Comment: I don't think he knows as well ... I guess he just hit it before he realized that it was not going to help min? Can I delete my answer so that you can post the appropriate answer, or should I just make this community wiki so that you can edit with the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

THE Code you are using is totally outdated. Way2sms change their way of authentication.
If you want to use new code then here is solution : http://ritesh-chandora.blogspot.in/2012/02/php-code-for-sending-free-sms.html
this blog will provide new way of sending sms easily.

Comment: this is only for India people. Requires to state the city in India and the number (apparently also Indian), so, won't work for other people.

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine, except one line
change this

```
if($result=='true')
to
if($result == true)
```

Comment: @ JapanPro,  thanks. Please guide me how to use it in my website? and how to set sms gateway? if i use this code is it enough to send sms through website?