# Sending free sms using PHP

Tags: php, curl, sms-gateway

I am trying to develop a PHP based application to send sms across India to contacts picked from the database. After searching for hours, I found the following working (I tested it) script which makes use of `fullonsms.com` as sms gateway but it sends a single message at a time and then loads the homepage.
But I don't know a lot about curl.

So

1. I need help to understand what is actually being done.
2. Secondly,how can I modify it to optimally send sms to multiple people(like will it be optimal to put it in a loop) without wasting data or unnecessary page loads.
   3.After sending each SMS ,it loads homepage.So won't it try to load the homepage before sending SMS.If yes,can I remove the starred(** **) line to prevent this.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $cookie_file_path = "/cookie.txt"; 
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $tomobno="1234567890";
    $message=urlencode("Hi buddy");  

          $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://sms.fullonsms.com/login.php");    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "MobileNoLogin=$username&LoginPassword=$password&x=16&y=14");
        $html=curl_exec($ch);
        **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://sms.fullonsms.com/home.php");**
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ActionScript=%2Fhome.php&CancelScript=%2Fhome.php&HtmlTemplate=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Ffullonsms%2FStaticSpamWarning.html&MessageLength=140&MobileNos=$tomobno&Message=$message&Gender=0&FriendName=Your+Friend+Name&ETemplatesId=&TabValue=contacts");

          $html = curl_exec($ch);
          echo $html;
?>
```

There's is a similar question asked but answer accepted is off the topic and it uses a different gateway [SMS sending through free gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360010/sms-sending-through-free-gateway)

Comment: check the documentation of the api you are using, there is no generic answer to this

Comment: @Dragon:The `fullonsms.com` doesn't provide any official API.

Comment: then use a sms provide that does

Comment: @Dagon : Can you please help me in understanding the curl code.

Comment: if they dont provide an api that probably don't want you doing this, just try not to get banned.

Comment: @Dagon : Its just a learning project.I will not do any illegal work ,just 4-5 SMSs and that's the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) I need help to understand what is actually being done.

The code is sending two HTTP requests to the service. The first request signs in with your username and password, and it stores the session cookies for the next request. The second request is the one that actually triggers the send, it takes the mobile number and other details as POST data. The second request is able to use the session created by the first request because of the cookiejar.

> 2) Secondly,how can I modify it to optimally send sms to multiple people

If the service allows you to input multiple mobile numbers (for example comma separated) then that would be most optimal because it would only require the two requests to send to all mobile numbers.

If not, you will have to loop the second request so that there is one request per mobile number. Remember to change the hardcoded POST data so that is uses the next mobile number and name, instead of sending to the same number each time.

I would also suggest pausing for a period of time after each iteration of the loop to prevent sending the requests too fast. You can use `sleep(1)` for example to wait for 1 second.

Comment: Sir , I have one question- How will I log out at the end?

Comment: You wouldn't need to log out because the session would just expire after the time limit, but if you really wanted to you would need to see how they do the logout request on their site to be able to replicate it with cuRL. For example it could be either a POST or GET request with some parameters.

Comment: What's the significance of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://sms.fullonsms.com/home.php");` line in the code above?Won't it try to unnecessarily load the homepage after each SMS?Can I eliminate it?

Comment: No you need to keep that, `home.php` is the script that triggers the send when you post data to it, so if you took that out, nothing would be sent. The line is just setting the URL for the cURL request.

Answer (score 0):

1) I find the [cURL options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) list very useful, and also google 'HTTP headers' and 'RESTful URL'.

2) You could wrap the code in a couple of functions, i.e. a function that determines whether there is only one or many recipients (perhaps using `is_array()`) and then a function which has parameters such as `$message, $recipients, $from, etc..` which uses a `foreach()` to loop through the recipient(s) passed to it by the first function